# SSRS CreateSubscription method - render format

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I am trying to set up a website that allows users to add themselves to subscriptions for reports.

The problem is that when I try and make the subscription render the report as "Excel" it sets it too "XML with report data".

The piece of code I use to try and change the render format is below;

```
        extParameters.Add(new ParameterValue() { Name = "RenderFormat", Value = "Excel" });
        extParameters.Add(new ParameterValue() { Name = "TO", Value = strEmail });
        extParameters.Add(new ParameterValue() { Name = "IncludeReport", Value = "True" });
        extParameters.Add(new ParameterValue() { Name = "Subject", Value = "subject - " + " (" + strReportPath + ")" });
```

Thank you

Comment: Solved it now. I had to put the RenderFormat value as "EXCEL" in caps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it now.

I had to put the RenderFormat value as "EXCEL" or "EXCELOPENXML"